# Spike and surge protection for electronic boards

Tags: surge-protection

I'd like to protect from spike, surge, and so on... an electronic interface that is powered from a 220V / 5V DC power module (*AZ Delivery AC-05-3*).
The board, designed by me, integrate and ESP 32 board and some other ICs.
I'm searching for an easy, cheap, and effective solution.
I need anything tha can easly integrated on the PCB.
Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Define the spike or aggressor and define the victim's withstand capabilities as they currently stand. Then design the bit to go in between.

Comment: You should define what you want to protect from spikes and surges. The mains input of power supply, or relay contacts? Also is the mains inlet area filled with ground plane - if so your product may not be up to safety standards and you should redesign the board.

Comment: @Justme
Hi. Thanks for reply. I'd like to protect, in order of importance: 1) ESP 32 board; 2) AC /DC power supply 3) relay and loads powered from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the load you are driving, and it also depends on what kind of surge rating you need because AC mains can throw a lot at a product (thousands of volt spikes from lightning and other transients) so I'll cover the basics. You could have something as simple as a line filter that filters out fast spikes from AC mains and also conducted emissions from switchers that might get back into the line from a power supply load side of the product

[image]
Source: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/transient-suppression.html

Some of them also have integrated fuses and switches:

[image]
https://www.schurter.com/en/products-and-solutions/catalog?(pg06)/1

Sometimes a crowbar circuit can be used (and is used in many devices such as power supplies) so when a high voltage spike comes in it activates a SCR and burns out a fuse

[image]
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/transient-suppression.html

MOV's can be used to also short out high voltage spikes.

[image]
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/transient-suppression.html

You can also find some products that have these features integrated into modules that could be integrated into a product external to the PCB.

Make sure you follow applicable specs like [IEC61010](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=iec%2061010) if you want the product certified, and if you don't it's a good idea to follow them anyway for saftey reasons. The cover insulation creepage and clearance on and off PCB's.

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your very interesting and fast reply. I'll study all.